# JPA query class from primary key

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

How would I query just for the class of an entity if I have it's primary key? I don't want to retrieve whole object, that seems unnecessary when I am just interested in the class of that object. I have tried

```
SELECT o.dtype FROM MyEntity o WHERE id = ?1
```

but that does not work.

Comment: I have multiple subclasses of Entity in persistence, and they have Long as their id. I would like to query for Long id source class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the actual class:

```sql
SELECT TYPE(e) FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.id = ?1
```

```java
Class<?> clazz = entityManager.createQuery(query, Class.class)
    .setParameter(1, id)
    .getSingleResult();
```

and the following gives you the discriminator value:

```sql
SELECT e.class FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.id = ?1
```

```java
String discr = entityManager.createQuery(query, String.class)
    .setParameter(1, id)
    .getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.dtype FROM MyEntity o WHERE o.id = ?1
```

You use alias for MyEntity as `o` use `o` to define column `id`.

Comment: How is that relevant? I have multiple subclasses of MyEntity and need to know which "subclass" it is without adding that explicitedly into persistence.

Comment: please can you explain what you want in question clearly ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this query works:

```
SELECT o.class FROM MyEntity o WHERE id = ?1
```

Example usage:

```
public static Class<? extends MyEntity> getClassOf(Long id) {
    TypedQuery<String> q = entityManager().createQuery(
            "SELECT o.class FROM MyEntity o WHERE id = ?1", 
            String.class);
    q.setParameter(1, id);
    q.setMaxResults(1);
    List<String> r = q.getResultList();
    if (r.size() == 0)
        return null;

    for (Package p : Package.getPackages()){
        if (p.getName().startsWith("mypackage.prefix")){
            try {
                return (Class<? extends MyEntity>) Class.forName(p.getName() + "." + r.get(0));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That will return the discriminator value, not the actual class. You would need a discriminator value that matches the class name, which is not necessarily always the case.